# How to change computer name for one application

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-foxpro, foxpro

How to change computer name for one Windows .exe file (Visual FoxPro application). Application gets computer name using sys(0) which probably makes some API call.
I tried to create .bat file with

```
set CLIENTNAME=mycompname1
set SESSIONNAME=mycompname1
myapp.exe
```

But application still gets real name.
How to ovveride API call so that one application only gets some other computer name than specified in computer properties ?

Comment: In the general case, there's no easy way to do this. You can use a technique called Windows *API Hooking* (if you know or managed to determine the API used), for example with things like this https://github.com/TsudaKageyu/minhook

Comment: You might trying putting those commands in a config.fpw file. It controls the environment variables that the program will use and it's usually in the folder where the fox is started.

Comment: @SimonMourier Since application source code is avaliable, I changed application to check CLIENTNAME_OVERRIDE environment variable for computer name before SYS(0)